# Nonlinear abscissa in TimelinePlot

Tags: plotting

I would like to produce a `TimelinePlot` in which the scale of the abscissa varies nonlinearly (compressing old dates and expanding recent dates).  Others have confronted related problems, such as here ([Non-linear scaled X axis in DateListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17495/non-linear-scaled-x-axis-in-datelistplot)) but those earlier solutions (merging separate `DateListPlots`, each with its own scale) will not work for me because I want the abscissa to vary *gradually* (like a log plot) and I will have `Interval`s that have *durations* that extend over wide periods.

I can of course include `Ticks` that correspond to nonlinear increments (e.g., for the years 1900, 1950, 1970, 1980, 1985, 1986, ...), but the spatial separation remains (alas) linear.

I have explored all options under `TimelinePlot` and related timed event display functions, without success.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to remap the time coordinate manually.

```
newData = ({scaleFunc[AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]]], #[[2]]} &) /@ origData;
```

Where the `scaleFunc` is your time scaling function. Then you would need to use a normal plot function and set the labels for the Ticks manually as well. (I know: Ick!)

This is similar to what i do to smooth time data or fitting time data. I hope that there's a better way and someone corrects me...

Comment: Rescaling the data is not likely to work because some of the displays will include the final date.  I want Kennedy's assassination to be November 22, 1963—and listed as such—not some transformed value.  Moreover, I'll want to compute some durations from the data, such as the delay between event 1 and event 2.  This of course will not work if I use the transformed data.  In short:  your suggestion simply will not work.

Comment: @David G. Stork Bummer. That's all i have for you then. Sorry i wasn't able to help! :^(